# Can't bind to 'model' since it isn't a known property of 'tag'

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

I'm trying to use ng2-tag-input to my ionic 2 app. But i get this error when do ionic run android with production mode(--prod).ng2-tag-input version is 0.7.2.

> build prod failed: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'readOnly'
>   since it isn't a known property of 'tag'. 
>               (" [attr.tabindex]="readonly ? -1 : 0" [class.readonly]="readonly" [ERROR ->][readonly]="readonly" 
>               [removable]="removable" [editable]="editable" "): TagInputComponent@17:13 Can't bind to 'removable' since it 
>               isn't a known property of 'tag'. (" [class.readonly]="readonly" [readonly]="readonly" [ERROR 
>               ->][removable]="removable" [editable]="editable" [displayBy]="displayBy" "): TagInputComponent@18:13 Can't 
>               bind to 'editable' since it isn't a known property of 'tag'. (" [readonly]="readonly" 
>               [removable]="removable" [ERROR ->][editable]="editable" [displayBy]="displayBy" [identifyBy]="identifyBy" 
>               "): TagInputComponent@19:13 Can't bind to 'displayBy' since it isn't a known property of 'tag'. (" 
>               [removable]="removable" [editable]="editable" [ERROR ->][displayBy]="displayBy" [identifyBy]="identifyBy" 
>               [template]="!!hasCustomTe"): TagInputComponent@20:13 Can't bind to 'identifyBy' since it isn't a known 
>               property of 'tag'. (" [editable]="editable" [displayBy]="displayBy" [ERROR ->][identifyBy]="identifyBy" 
>               [template]="!!hasCustomTemplate() ? templates.first : undefine"): TagInputComponent@21:13 Can't bind to 
>               'template' since it isn't a known property of 'tag'. (" [displayBy]="displayBy" [identifyBy]="identifyBy" 
>               [ERROR ->][template]="!!hasCustomTemplate() ? templates.first : undefined" [model]="item"> "): 
>               TagInputComponent@22:13 Can't bind to 'model' since it isn't a known property of 'tag'. ("ntifyBy" 
>               [template]="!!hasCustomTemplate() ? templates.first : undefined" [ERROR ->][model]="item">  "): 
>               TagInputComponent@23:13 'tag' is not a known element: 1. If 'tag' is an Angular component, then verify that 
>               it is part of this module. 2. If 'tag' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the 
>               '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("   [ERROR ->] ][@flyInOut]="'in'" 
>               (onSelect)="selectItem(item)" (onRemove)="removeItem(ite"): TagInputComponent@10:13  [15:28:08] 
>   ionic-app-script task: "build"  [15:28:08]  Error: Template parse
>   errors: Can't bind to 'readOnly' since it isn't a known property of
>   'tag'. (" 
>               [attr.tabindex]="readonly ? -1 : 0" [class.readonly]="readonly" [ERROR ->][readonly]="readonly" 
>               [removable]="removable" [editable]="editable" "): TagInputComponent@17:13 Can't bind to 'removable' since it 
>               isn't a known property of 'tag'. (" [class.readonly]="readonly" [readonly]="readonly" [ERROR 
>               ->][removable]="removable" [editable]="editable" [displayBy]="displayBy" "): TagInputComponent@18:13 Can't 
>               bind to 'editable' since it isn't a known property of 'tag'. (" [readonly]="readonly" 
>               [removable]="removable" [ERROR ->][editable]="editable" [displayBy]="displayBy" [identifyBy]="identifyBy" 
>               "): TagInputComponent@19:13 Can't bind to 'displayBy' since it isn't a known property of 'tag'. (" 
>               [removable]="removable" [editable]="editable" [ERROR ->][displayBy]="displayBy" [identifyBy]="identifyBy" 
>               [template]="!!hasCustomTe"): TagInputComponent@20:13 Can't bind to 'identifyBy' since it isn't a known 
>               property of 'tag'. (" [editable]="editable" [displayBy]="displayBy" [ERROR ->][identifyBy]="identifyBy" 
>               [template]="!!hasCustomTemplate() ? templates.first : undefine"): TagInputComponent@21:13 Can't bind to 
>               'template' since it isn't a known property of 'tag'. (" [displayBy]="displayBy" [identifyBy]="identifyBy" 
>               [ERROR ->][template]="!!hasCustomTemplate() ? templates.first : undefined" [model]="item"> "): 
>               TagInputComponent@22:13 Can't bind to 'model' since it isn't a known property of 'tag'. ("ntifyBy" 
>               [template]="!!hasCustomTemplate() ? templates.first : undefined" [ERROR ->][model]="item">  "): 
>               TagInputComponent@23:13 'tag' is not a known element: 1. If 'tag' is an Angular component, then verify that 
>               it is part of this module. 2. If 'tag' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the 
>               '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("   [ERROR ->] ][@flyInOut]="'in'" 
>               (onSelect)="selectItem(item)" (onRemove)="removeItem(ite"): TagInputComponent@10:13  Error: Template
>   parse errors: Can't bind to 'readOnly' since it isn't a known property
>   of 'tag'. ("          [attr.tabindex]="readonly ? -1 : 0"
>                [class.readonly]="readonly"
>                [ERROR ->][readonly]="readonly"
>                [removable]="removable"
>                [editable]="editable" "): TagInputComponent@17:13 Can't bind to 'removable' since it isn't a known property of 'tag'. ("
>                [class.readonly]="readonly"
>                [readonly]="readonly"
>                [ERROR ->][removable]="removable"
>                [editable]="editable"
>                [displayBy]="displayBy" "): TagInputComponent@18:13 Can't bind to 'editable' since it isn't a known property of 'tag'. ("
>                [readonly]="readonly"
>                [removable]="removable"
>                [ERROR ->][editable]="editable"
>                [displayBy]="displayBy"
>                [identifyBy]="identifyBy" "): TagInputComponent@19:13 Can't bind to 'displayBy' since it isn't a known property of 'tag'. ("
>                [removable]="removable"
>                [editable]="editable"
>                [ERROR ->][displayBy]="displayBy"
>                [identifyBy]="identifyBy"
>                [template]="!!hasCustomTe"): TagInputComponent@20:13 Can't bind to 'identifyBy' since it isn't a known property of 'tag'.
>   ("
>                [editable]="editable"
>                [displayBy]="displayBy"
>                [ERROR ->][identifyBy]="identifyBy"
>                [template]="!!hasCustomTemplate() ? templates.first : undefine"): TagInputComponent@21:13 Can't bind to 'template' since it
>   isn't a known property of 'tag'. ("
>                [displayBy]="displayBy"
>                [identifyBy]="identifyBy"
>                [ERROR ->][template]="!!hasCustomTemplate() ? templates.first : undefined"
>                [model]="item">
>          "): TagInputComponent@22:13 Can't bind to 'model' since it isn't a known property of 'tag'. ("ntifyBy"
>                [template]="!!hasCustomTemplate() ? templates.first : undefined"
>                [ERROR ->][model]="item">
>
> "): TagInputComponent@23:13 'tag' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'tag' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'tag' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
>       
>       
>           [ERROR ->]
>           ][@flyInOut]="'in'"
>                (onSelect)="selectItem(item)"
>                (onRemove)="removeItem(ite"): TagInputComponent@10:13
>       at TemplateParser.parse (/Users/Thayadha/Documents/panitr-mobile-v2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:7730:21)
>       at OfflineCompiler._compileComponent (/Users/Thayadha/Documents/panitr-mobile-v2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:12864:53)
>       at /Users/Thayadha/Documents/panitr-mobile-v2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:12808:115
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at OfflineCompiler._compileSrcFile (/Users/Thayadha/Documents/panitr-mobile-v2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:12792:22)
>       at /Users/Thayadha/Documents/panitr-mobile-v2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:12777:76
>       at Array.map (native)
>       at /Users/Thayadha/Documents/panitr-mobile-v2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:12777:41

Could anyone suggest me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Please provide the template.

Comment: This is  my template code: <tag-input formControlName="tags" [placeholder]="options.placeholder" [secondaryPlaceholder]="options.secondaryPlaceholder"
            [maxItems]="options.maxItems" [(ngModel)]="post.tags">
          </tag-input>

Comment: are you sure it's the right template ? Non of issues seems to be related.

Comment: Yes.Its correct. i don't know where i did wrong.

Comment: Can you give the template of the tag-input component.

Comment: This is what i did in the component. options = {
        placeholder: "+ tag",
        secondaryPlaceholder: "Enter a new tag",
        separatorKeys: [4, 5],
        maxItems: 10
    }   this.post = { "tags": [ "real", "apart", "abc" ] };

Comment: That's not the template, that's some Typescript.

Comment: <tag-input formControlName="tags" [placeholder]="+ tag" [secondaryPlaceholder]="Enter a new tag" [maxItems]="10" [(ngModel)]="post.tags"> </tag-input>

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought you created this component. That's why I kept asking for its template but you didn't. Did you manage to get it to work at some point or did it never work ? All I can recommend at this point is to make sure you installed it correctly.

Comment: I have post json in my component. In Template, That tag input code is there. Actually, I have tried all possible ways. It dint work. Is there any npm package for tag input in ionic 2?

Comment: If this package is incompatible with Ionic (or AOT, I don't know if Ionic is using AOT compilation) the only solution that comes to my mind is to create your own tag input.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you!